# How to reformulate a 1/x^2 singular term to 1/x so that bvp4c can solve it?

Tags: matlab, ode, boundary-conditions

I have a ''cosmetic'' problem with a singular term in my Matlab script. I am trying to solve the following system of differential equations:
$$ \begin{aligned}
y_1' &= y_2,\\
y_2' &= \frac{2y_1}{x^2}+k(y_1^3 - y_1) - \frac{2y_2}{x}.
\end{aligned}$$

Where x is the independent variable of y and k is a constant. This system is to be solved with the boundary conditions:
$$\begin{aligned}
y_1(0)&=0,\\
y_1(10) &= 1.
\end{aligned}$$

I have a working script for this with Matlab's bvp4c function. However, the solution for $y_2$ appears to go off to infinity near zero. I've read from Matlab's documentation that bvp4c can solve problems with singular boundary values if they are of the form:
$$y' = S \cdot \frac{y}{x} + F(x,y,p).$$
But as you can see there is a $\frac{1}{x^2}$-term in addition to a $\frac{1}{x}$-term. I've been trying to modify the form of the differential equation such that I could write it in the form Matlab wants it to be. However, whatever I do I can't seem to be able to modify it to the desired form. I was hoping that maybe someone might have some insight to this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried a subsitution, e.g. $Y_{1,2}=\frac{y_{1,2}}{x}$? That should transform the equation into the required form.

Comment: Yes, but I can't seem to get anywhere with it. Could you show how you would continue with that substitution? I end up with a matrix S of the form:

$S = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ 2 & 0   \end{bmatrix} $

Then for the ODE-function I have :

$Y_1' = Y_2$

$Y_2' = k(Y_1^3 - Y_1) - 2Y_2$


With the singular term inserted as instructed in Matlab's documentation.

Comment: Perhaps it might be easier to use a shooting method? It's easy to get the Taylor series at $x=0$ to specify an initial condition at a small positive $x$, and it avoids the problems with bvp4c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation, written as a 2nd-order ODE, is
$$ y'' = -\frac{2}{x}y' + \frac{2}{x^2}y + ky(y^2-1). $$
Substituting
$$ y(x) = x w(x), $$
it becomes
$$ w'' = -\frac{4}{x}w' + k w(1 - x^2 w^2), $$
which matches the form accepted by bvp4c with the matrix
$$ S = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ -4 & 0 \end{pmatrix}. $$
Other transformations of the form $y=(x+\alpha x^{-2})w$ also get it to this kind of form.

There is, in fact, a well-known theory of changes of variables in
linear ODEs (see, for example, this theorem due to Liouville:
https://mathoverflow.net/a/187499), and finding a transformation like
$y=xw$ doesn't actually require any guesswork. Applying the transformations to the first-order form of the ODE in $(y_1,y_2)$ makes this unnecessarily unwieldy.

Comment: Is it a problem that with this transform the BC become $w(0)=\infty$?

Comment: @nluigi How do you mean? $y(0)=0$ becomes the condition that $w(0)$ is finite, and $w(0)$ is just the unknown $y'(0)$.

Comment: it seems to me $w(0)=y(0)/0$ is undefined, hence my question. Why do you say it is finite?

Comment: @nluigi Expand $y$ in Taylor series at $x=0$, then expand $w$ in Taylor series, then equate coefficients in $y=xw$. Writing $w=y/x$ is the wrong way to go about doing that—it's the expression $y(0)/0$ that is undefined, not the boundary condition itself. And in any case, if $y$ is a solution, then $y(0)=0$ and $y$ is a suitably differentiable function, so $w$ definitely exists and is finite. And if $w$ is a solution that remains finite at $0$, then $y=xw$ is a solution of the equation in $y$.

Comment: @nluigi In fact, a solution to $0=0x$ is *not* $x=0/0$, which is meaningless, but $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: OK, thx for clearing that up